# When to create multiple containers in Azure Cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am creating multiple micro service APIs. Can we use one single Container to store all the different schemas from the different APIs? If so how to differentiate the schemas while retrieving documents? When to create multiple containers in Azure Cosmos dB? is that any disadvantages/caveats of using multiple containers?
Please Explain.

Comment: You've asked 3 different questions here, some of it opinion-based, and there's really no single objectively-correct answer for any of these. There is a general philosophy behind microservices and single-purpose data stores. You'd need to come up w/your own scheme for different docs (maybe a `type` property) since there is no enforced schema.  As for advantages/caveats: lots of material written around this (scaling, partitioning, cost, etc). I would start with the Cosmos DB docs, plus existing questions here.